# Animated Splash Screen in Ionic 4 and Angular 8

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, animation, splash-screen

I am working on a gps related mobile application using **ionic 4 and angular 8**
So at the beginning of app means in splash screen, client wants to get animated splash screen
Where the location icon should blink.
Is it possible? and if Yes please let me know how can I achieve that

Comment: this is older article (ionic 3) but directionally it is about what you need: https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-an-animated-splash-screen-in-ionic/ Please provide your current implementation and describe what the issue is implementing it?

Comment: Actually, I never have done the animation in splash screen.
Can we add .gif in splash screen?

Comment: depends on implementation and what you call "SplashScreen" - native app splash? pre-framework bootstrapped splash? post framework bootstrap splash (basically first page). I would suggest you describe exact experience you want to get and try implementing it, then share code you had that far with specific question